# How to count number of times a file was executed on linux

Tags: linux, stat

I have an executable file and I would like to know how many times it is being executed. The file is located on a network file system. Is there a way to do this with a script using one of Linux utilities? The limitation I have is that I would like to avoid changing the file itself. For example I will not add a file with a counter which would be updated by an executable script. And I will not make the executable script call some API to increment a counter in e.g. database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how to watch a file for execution, but you can construct something with `inotify` watching how many times it is opened:

You could have a script like that:

```
#! /bin/bash

EXEC_CNT=0
FILE_TO_WATCH=/path/to/your/file
while inotifywait -e open "$FILE_TO_WATCH" 
do 
   ((EXEC_CNT++))
   echo "$FILE_TO_WATCH opened $EXEC_CNT times" 
   # Or to store in a file:
   # echo "$FILE_TO_WATCH opened $EXEC_CNT times" >> "$FILE_TO_WATCH.log"
done
```

---

In case of a network share, this script must be runned on the computer that share its file system.

Comment: Thanks, this does work. However not in my case. I have a network disk mounted. Reading a bit more about `inotify` and it's details, I figured that what I'm trying to do is not possible. Only way is to run something like `inotify` on the machine which physically hosts the disk. If you add this to your answer I will accept it.